# How to extract data with beautifulsoup with similar attributes

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape a saved html page of results and copy the entries for each and iterate through the document.  However I can't figure out how to narrow down the element to start.  The data I want to grab is in the "td" tags below each of the following "tr" tags:

```
<tr bgcolor="#d7d7d7">
<td valign="top" nowrap="">
Submittal<br>20190919-5000
<!-- ParentAccession= -->
<br>
</td>
<td valign="top">
    09/18/2019<br>
    09/19/2019
</td>
<td valign="top" nowrap="">
    ER19-2760-000<br>ER19-2762-000<br>ER19-2763-000<br>ER19-2764-000<br>ER1    9-2765-000<br>ER19-2766-000<br>ER19-2768-000<br><br>
</td>
<td valign="top">
(doc-less) Motion to Intervene of Snohomish County Public Utility     District No. 1 under ER19-2760, et. al..<br>Availability: Public<br>
</td>
<td valign="top">
<classtype>Intervention /<br> Motion/Notice of     Intervention</classtype>
</td>
<td valign="top">
<table valign="top">


<input type="HIDDEN" name="ext" value="TXT"><tbody><tr><td     valign="top"> <input type="checkbox" name="subcheck"    value="V:14800341:12904817:15359058:TXT"></td><td>&nbsp;<a    href="../common/opennat.asp?fileID=15359058">Text</a></td><td>&nbsp;&  nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;0K</td></tr><input type="HIDDEN" name="ext" value="PDF"><tr><td valign="top"> <input type="checkbox"      name="subcheck" value="V:14800341:12904822:15359063:PDF"></td><td>&nbsp;<a href="../common/opennat.asp?fileID=15359063">FERC Generated PDF</a></td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;11K</td></tr>

    </tbody></table>
</td>
```

The next tag is:  with the same structure as the one above.  These alternate so the results are in different colors on the results page.
I need to go through all of the subsequent td tags and grab the data but they aren't differentiated by a class or anything I can zero in on.  The code I wrote grabs the entire contents of the td tags text and appends it but I need to treat each td tag as a separate item and then do the same for the next entry etc.

By setting the td[0] value I start at the first td tag but I don't think this is the correct approach.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib
import re
soup = BeautifulSoup(open("/Users/Desktop/FERC/uploads/ferris_9-19-2019-9-19-2019.electric.submittal.html"), "html.parser")


data = []

for td in soup.findAll(bgcolor=["#d7d7d7", "White"]):
    values = [td[0].text.strip() for td in td.findAll('td')]
    data.append(values)
    print(data)
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. You should post more of the html above and below your snippet and, especially, an example of your expected output.

Comment: Please add in example of desired output and perhaps pastebin.com link to the html document.

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  Here's the html: https://pastebin.com/hZ5Xpj7R.  I am looking to scrape the entries for the details in all of these tags: <tr bgcolor="#d7d7d7">  and <tr bgcolor="White">

Comment: Having the html is a step in the right direction. Now, equally important: it's not clear what " the entries for the details in all of these tags" means. Please post your exact expected output for the html snippet in your question.

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to get the text for each td tag and the links for each then iterate over each subsequent bgcolor tag